# multi-boundary API call not working in Python

Tags: python, http

I have a working API call in Postman and I'm trying to replicate the call in Python. I started with the boilerplate code Postman provided and made some changes, but the API call is not working. I pulled a Wireshark log with a working call via Postman and compared it against my API call, and I think I may have found the issue, but I don't know how to fix it.

How can I update my Python code based on these findings below?

Here is a picture of the Wireshark call. The content-type of the first boundary is `application/json`.

[image]

However, the actual call being made doesn't include the content-type `application/json` and I'm not sure if the JSON string is being passed correctly.

```
>>> response.request.body
b'--affc9f680a99e3d8509e8c9f24b422b3\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="documentAttributes"\r\n\r\n{"batchInfo":{"batchName":"YMTESTALIAS","createDateTime":"2023-05-22T14:00:00.000Z"},"batchDocumentInfo":{"documentTypeName":"Photo Identification","subject":"Alias Test","metadata":[{"fieldName":"MRN","fieldValue":"9305940"},{"fieldName":"ENCTR_NBR","fieldValue":"65013813"}]},"processQueue":"BATCH","indexImmediately":"true"}\r\n--affc9f680a99e3d8509e8c9f24b422b3\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="documentContent"; filename="hello.tif"\r\nContent-Type: image/tiff\r\n\r\nII*\x002\x19\x00\x00\x80?\xe0@\x0
```

Here is the code

```
import requests
import json

domain = 'cert'
client_mnemonic = 'xxxx_fl'
auth_token = 'Basic .....=='
file_path = 'C:/Users/system/Desktop/hello.tif'

url = f'http://1.1.1.1/docimaging-access-1.0/{domain}.{client_mnemonic}.cernerasp.com/service/documents'

batch_name = 'TESTALIAS'
document_type = 'Photo Identification'
subject = 'Alias Test'
mrn = '9305940'
fin = '65013813'

# build payload
payload = {
    'documentAttributes': {
        'batchInfo': {
            'batchName': f'{batch_name}',
            'createDateTime': '2023-10-31T14:00:00.000Z'
        },
        'batchDocumentInfo': {
            'documentTypeName': f'{document_type}',
            'subject': f'{subject}',
            'metadata': [
                {
                    'fieldName': 'MRN',
                    'fieldValue': f'{mrn}'
                },
                {
                    'fieldName': 'ENCTR_NBR',
                    'fieldValue': f'{fin}'
                }
            ]
        },
        'processQueue':'BATCH',
        'indexImmediately':'true'
    }
}

headers = {
    'Authorization': auth_token
}

files = {
    'documentContent': ('hello.tif', open(file_path,'rb'), 'image/tiff')
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)
```

Comment: Can you provide a more complete picture of the expected http request

Answer (score 0):

Use the `files` argument to encapsulate all multi-part parts.

```py
payload = {
    "batchInfo": {
        "batchName": f"{batch_name}",
        "createDateTime": "2023-10-31T14:00:00.000Z",
    },
    "batchDocumentInfo": {
        "documentTypeName": f"{document_type}",
        "subject": f"{subject}",
        "metadata": [
            {"fieldName": "MRN", "fieldValue": f"{mrn}"},
            {"fieldName": "ENCTR_NBR", "fieldValue": f"{fin}"},
        ],
    },
    "processQueue": "BATCH",
    "indexImmediately": "true",
}

files = {
    'documentContent': ('hello.tif', open(file_path,'rb'), 'image/tiff'),
    'documentAttributes': (None, json.dumps(payload).encode(), 'application/json'),
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, files=files)
```